# Открытие подменю при наведении курсора

Tags: меню, html, css

Здравствуйте! Как сделать чтобы при наведении курсора на вертикальное меню , категория открывалась? Открывалась вправо. Ни вниз, ни вверх, а вправо.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по вашей HTML-структуре, на валидацию, как я понимаю, вы чихать хотели )) Ну да ладно... jQuery вы используете, поэтому прописываете для списка подкатегорий абсолютное позиционирование в CSS, а в JS высчитываете положение родительского пункта меню

```
var posTop = $('parent_point').offset().top;
var posLeft = $('parent_point').offset().left + $('parent_point').width();
```

и задаете эти координаты для списка подпунктов.

Answer (score 3):

Я делал решениеи с использование только CSS для несложного меню.
HTML код:

```
<div class="main_menu_item">
    <a href="/billing/">Billing</a>
    <div class="submenu">
        <div><a href="/billing/">Manage orders and invoices</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS код:

```
.submenu
{
    display: none;   
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 5px;border: 1px solid #6B93FF;
}

div.main_menu_item:hover div
{
    display: block;
}
```

При наведение курсора на ссылку "Billing" Отобразится его подменю, в котором будет ссылка "Manage orders and invoices"

Comment: Поддерживаю решение на CSS. Могу добавить, что выпендрежа ради, можно попробовать не display: none/block, а opacity: 0/1. В случае с прозрачностью можно добавить плавное проявление подменю при помощи transition или animation. Однако, обратите внимание на то, что полностью прозрачные блоки, в отличии от display: none, укладываются поверх других слоев, которые могут содержать кликабельные элементы. Так что помимо opacity нужно еще и с z-index поиграть.

Так же задумайтесь, что будет с вашем меню на ТАЧ-устройствах.

Answer (score 2):

И так если не подключая никаких скриптов обычно используя html и css то решение таково или по крайней мере как сделал бы я:

html содержание то есть само меню

---

<!--menu start-->

```
<ul class="menu">

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__item__link">Home</a>
        <div class="menu__item__sublist">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

    <li class="menu__item">
        <a href="#" class="menu__item__link">About</a>
        <div class="menu__item__sublist">
            <ul>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu__item__sublist_item">
                    <a href="#" class="menu__item__sublist_link">Submenu1</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>

</ul>
<!--menu end-->
```

Теперь сам CSS

/ *menu
   -------------------------*/

```
.menu {
    width: 98px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }

    /* menu__item
       -------------------------*/
    .menu__item {
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        }

        /* menu__item__link
           -------------------------*/
        .menu__item__link {
            display: block;
            text-decoration: none;
            }

        /* menu__item__sublist
           -------------------------*/
        .menu__item__sublist {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 98px;
            padding: 0 0 0 2px;
            display: none;
            }
        .menu__item:hover .menu__item__sublist { display: block; }

            /* menu__item__sublist UL
               -------------------------*/
            .menu__item__sublist UL {
                }

                .menu__item__sublist_item {
                    list-style-type: none;
                    }

                    .menu__item__sublist_link {
                        display: block;
                        text-decoration: none;
                        }
```

Ширина меню задана (98px) для того чтобы выпадающее меню у вас было закреплено. Если уберете бордер то не забудьте два пикселя вернуть (100px). Остально думаю по комментам разберете.